# What is the HostKey?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

In my sshd_config, there is three lines for the HostKey :

```
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
```

What is that ? I mean, I know what to do with public/private keys, but why there is keys in my server that don't belongs to me and who, apparently, are there for identify users ?

Answer (score 0):

The server also needs its own key pair to participate in public key cryptography.